# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions error when deleting via services

Tags: c#, nhibernate, service, fluent-nhibernate

There are several posts related to this error but I'm running into something different.

Very simple NHibernate scenario. Parent and child tables with one to many relationship. One parent can have multiple children.

I need to delete a Parent record with child records so I put together very basic code which works fine:

```
var childRecordList = new List<ChildRecord>();

var parentRecord = ParentRecordRepository.Get(parentRecordId);
childRecordList = ChildRecordRepository.GetAll().Where(c=>c.ParentRecord.Id==parentRecord.Id);

foreach(var childRecord in childRecordList)
{
 ChildRecordRepository.Delete(childRecord);
}

ParentRecordRepository.Delete(parentRecord);
```

Works. Deletes child and the parent records.

If I take the logic above and turn it into a Services method as "`DeleteRecord(ParentRecord parentRecord)`" it starts failing with the **Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions** error on `ParentRecordRepository.Delete(parentRecord);`

Services are called by instantiating a service class and then calling the DeleteRecord method:

```
var parentRecord = ParentRecordRepository.Get(id);

var recordService = new RecordService();
recordService.DeleteRecord(parentRecord);
```

Can't figure out why. Help ?

Comment: Why do you have explicit "repository" classes? Is "ParentRecordRespository.Get" simply masking "session.Get<ParentRecord>(parentRecordId)"?

Comment: For the sake of example to make things easier. Ofcourse I can write up more details and expand on the BaseRepository I have that implements the base repository functions interface. It's not needed though I believe and will only confuse people.

Comment: Are you opening a session in BOTH the `ParentRecordRepository` and
 the `ChildRecordRepository` ? This is the problem, opening a session should happen once per request/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating a session by instantiating an instance of the repository and then doing operation on an object pulled from it.
Then I would open a new session of the repository within the Service layer and try to delete the object passed from the controller created session with it. That was the problem.

The bottom line is the same session has to used to both get and delete an object.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your working example I'm a bit suspicious about what your `ParentRepository` is doing to populate it's children. If you have cascade options set up correctly and the mapping includes the child object definitions with the parent, then you shouldn't be deleting children independently, and deleting the parent would work, including deleting the children as expected. If I had to guess, I'd be expecting to see something like:

```
ChildRecordRepository.GetAll().Where(c=>c.ParentId == Id);
```

somewhere in the parent `Repository.Get` callstack where the parent and child repositories are using different `Session` instances.

Perhaps provide the mapping configuration for parent and child, and the contents of the parent's `Get()` method.

Comment: +1 as this could definitely help someone but this is not the case in my situation.